# Add image to file Word using addHtml in PhpWord

Tags: html, phpword

I have a question in PhpWord i'm trying to add image to word using Html code, but this is doesn't work.
I used visual studio code and the image is on the folder public.
Thanks you to help me.

```php
$html = '<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
    <td>Content</td>
    <td> <img src'.public_path().'/phone.jpg></td>
  </tr>
</table>';

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Asked almost a month ago, you've probably figured this out already? Looks like your 'src' attribute is missing an "=" after it. Also, pretty sure html insists on the attribute value being inside quotation marks, even though this would be allowed in css - that might throw phpword off, not sure.